# Counting number of appeareances of a certain value in r

Tags: r, vector, count, repeat

Let's say we have a vector `a <- c(1,2,3,4,1,5,6,1,7)` and I want a function that would return the number of repetitions of each value. The results I want to get are `c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,1)` - because number 1 is being repeated 3 times.

The second question -  how to get a function which would return `c(1,0,0,0,2,0,0,3,0)` for the values above? So it would count only the elements that are being repeated and all others would get a 0?

Thank you!

Comment: For the second one, you could use `b <- duplicated(a) | duplicated(a, fromLast=TRUE); cumsum(b) * (b)`. This works for the example, but would not extend to multiple duplicate values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ave` function:

```
ave(rep(1, length(a)), a, FUN=cumsum)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 1
```

Following @lmo's comment, for the second part:

```
alldups <- duplicated(a) | duplicated(a, fromLast = TRUE)
res <- ave(rep(1, length(a)), a, FUN=cumsum)
res[!alldups] <- 0
# [1] 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 0
```

Comment: Ok, this was quite helpful, but what if the first vector was a character one, say c('a','b','c','a','d', 'e','a','f')

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether the vector is character or numeric. The above approach works for both cases.

Comment: I still have to check it, but I will be away 2 days - I report when I come back...

Comment: Thank you for your help! It worked. Can you just explain me what this ave command does? I tried reading through the help file but it was really unclear.

Comment: `ave` function is essentially an group operation, i.e, split the first vector by the second vector so that each subset contains same elements from the second vector and then apply the function to each subset of the first vector. For instance, if you have `ave(c(1,2,3,4), c(1,1,2,2), FUN=sum)` and then the sum will be applied as `c(sum(1,2), sum(1,2), sum(3,4), sum(3,4))` as the first two elements share `1` in the second vector, and the last two elements share `2` in the second vector. Hope this helps to understand.

Answer (score 0):

One option is

```
unsplit(lapply(split(a, a), function(x) cumsum(duplicated(x))+1),a)
```

Or with `ave`

```
res <- ave(a, a, FUN = function(x) cumsum(duplicated(x))+1)
res
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 1
```

and the second part

```
res[duplicated(res)] <- 0
res
#[1] 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `sapply`

```
temp <- sapply(1:length(a),function(x) sum(a[1:x] == a[x]))
temp
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 1

And for the second one:

temp[duplicated(temp)] <- 0
```